# Script in my browser is different from file I have in my code editor. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to shake my login form on the basis of a variable, which is empty if the login credentials are correct. This variable is `msg`.

Now if you see this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/K67Ct/2/) (test by clicking on Run, it will shake), it works fine but if I try to use in my application then it gives error as `$this is not defined` in line `$this.css({`.

I have written `$(this).css({` in my code but the console shows error with `$this.css({`.

Note that it does not have to do anything with the variable because I'm getting the variable from server side like when the user fills wrong credentials `$message` is non empty. I've checked this condition using the `alert box`.

I'm using jQuery 1.7 in my application.

Code used in my app is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="xyz/js/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("input:text:visible:first").focus();
var msg = "$message"
if (msg.length!==0){
alert("message is not empty");
jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes, intDistance, intDuration) {
  this.each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      position: "relative"
    });
    for (var x = 1; x <= intShakes; x++) {
      $(this).animate({
        left: (intDistance * -1)
      }, (((intDuration / intShakes) / 4))).animate({
        left: intDistance
      }, ((intDuration / intShakes) / 2)).animate({
        left: 0
      }, (((intDuration / intShakes) / 4)));
    }
  });
  return this;
};
$('#login').shake(2, 13, 250); }   });</script>

</head>
<body class="login login-action-login wp-core-ui">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="login">
    <form name="form_login1" action="$action" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login">

    <p><label>Username<br>
    <if condition="enable_password_cookie">
        <input type="text" name="login2" value="$login_from_password_cookie" onchange="document.form_login2.login.value = this.value" id="user_login" class="input" size="20" tabindex="1">
    </if>
    <else>
        <input type="text" id="user_login" class="input" name="login2" size="20" onchange="document.form_login2.login.value = this.value">
    </else>
       </label></p>        
    </form>

    <form name="form_login2" action="$action" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="login">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login">
        <input type="hidden" name="extra_param" value="$extra_param">
        <p>
                <label>Password
        <input type="password" name="password" is="password" id="password" class="input" value="" size="20">
        </label>
            </p>     

  <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="javascript:submit_login();" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large">
    </p><br><br>
     <p class="error">$message</p>  

</div><br>

    </form>

</div>       
</div>
</html>
```

PS: I've tried cleaning cache, but still I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFUF.png

EDIT 2: I've cleaned cache and all the browser data but still I can see that it's changing `$(this).css` to `$this.css`. I don't get why? :/

Comment: can you tell more about error you are getting?

Comment: Have you clear the cache?

Comment: there is no `$this` in your code, clear your cache

Comment: See the updated question with imgur link.

Comment: So, have you clear the cache???

Comment: Have you save your file and updated to the server?

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, have you uploaded the code to your site? Are sure the file your browser getting is the same you have in your code editor?

Comment: Yes, the site has the updated code. To test it I opened the file from site again and it's showing updated code. BTW it was never `$this.css`, it was always `$(this).css`, but I can see that it gets converted to `$this.css` when browser loads it.

Comment: Are you sure you never have written: $this?!  It's realy really strange

Comment: How do you clear cache?  See network tab for cached files

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, post your site here.

Comment: It's an intra network site, not available for public.

Comment: To be sure, modify your code by e.g adding alert(), is the alert() show? Are your files server cached?

Comment: Yes the alert is showing fine. No they are not being cached by server.

Comment: Can you tell an alternative to $(this)? Because I think since my template is being parsed using Perl script so $ may cause problem.

Comment: You have wait 25 min to tell us your code is parsed, seriously?!

Comment: I've used jQuery (with $ variable) in my application a lot of time (all being parsed by Perl script) but they didn't show any problem. `$("input:text:visible:first").focus();` also works fine. I don't think it's a problem with parsing. But still I want to confirm it so I asked for an alternative.

Comment: Check if $(this) is parsed:  var self = this; then use $(self)

Comment: Now it converts into `$self.css` instead of `$(self).css`.

Comment: same for $( self )? << see spaces

Comment: But I think you're right, because if there was no problem with parsing then it would have worked fine like jsfiddle.

Comment: YESSSSSSS! YOU ARE RIGHT. Adding a space like $( this ) solved the issue! Please add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[roasted's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979697/script-in-my-browser-is-different-from-file-i-have-in-my-code-editor-why#comment24528055_16979697) solved my problem.

I had to change `$(this)` to `$( this )`.

Answer (score 0):

1) `this` in your case is not jquery object. Use `$(this)`

2) Update cache of your application if browser shows code different from what you have in actual directory.

3) what you see in your browser debugger is actual code your browser getting. If you're sure that the code with $this instead of $(this) is actual code, just replace $this with $(this)

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, your browser getting piece of old code. Make sure your browser is getting up-to-date code. There is nothing wrong in code you posted here

Comment: Yes, it's changing `$(this)` to `$this`. But I never wrote `$this`. I have cleared the cache too.

Comment: I don't get why it's changing `$(this)` to `$this`

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, what you see on your screenshot is actual code your browser getting. If you're sure that the code with `$this` instead of `$(this)` is actual code, just replace `$this` with `$(this)`